# How to query field names from custom object by data type?

Tags: apex, query

I have custom object ExchangeRate__c. How to get all fields, which have data type "currency" and put their field names in a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below method and pass the object name `ExchangeRate__c` as parameter:

```
public static String getCurrencyFields(String obj) {
    List<String> fields = new List<String>();
    SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(obj);
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfieldsMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();

    for(Schema.SObjectField fld : mfieldsMap.values()) {
        if(fld.getDescribe().getType()==Schema.DisplayType.CURRENCY){
            fields.add(fld.getDescribe().getName());
        }
    }
    return String.join(fields,',');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I made a little mistake - I need field labels, not field names.

Comment: You can get label instead of name - `fields.add(fld.getDescribe().getLabel());`

Comment: Improvement suggestion - pass in `SObjectType` rather than `String` as that is more typesafe and avoid the lookup into GlobalDescribe. You can also get the sobjectType from string more efficiently using:  `Type t = Type.forName(name);
    SobjectType sobjType = ((SObject)t.newInstance()).getSObjectType();`

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't use a query for this, but rather the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) and [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe) classes.

`Schema.SObjectType.<Sobject API Name>.fields` gives you a `Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>` containing the field tokens for all of the fields on the object

You can then iterate over those `Schema.SObjectField` instances, and get the `DescribeFieldResult` from them using the `getDescribe()` method.

The `DescribeFieldResult` class gives you access to the metadata of the field, including what type of field it is (the `getType()` method).